# How to include a JSP page in a Facelets page?

Tags: jsp, jsf, include, facelets

I am using Myfaces 2 on Facelets.
I have to include a JSP page in a Facelet page.
I tried using `<ui:include>` but it takes only XHTML pages.
I also tried using `<c:import>` and `<f:subview>` but nothing worked.
Googled a lot but didn't get the exact answer.

How can I achieve the requirement?

Answer (score 4):

That's possible with a custom `UIComponent`. My fellow colleague has written a blog article about this a year ago: [Facelets and legacy JSP](http://jdevelopment.nl/facelets-legacy-jsp/).

It's some code, but the principle is easy, the component does a [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) with a custom [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) which captures the written output and then writes it to the body of the JSF component. Here are extracts of relevance:

Create class `com.example.component.JspIncludeComponent`

```java
public class JSPIncludeComponent extends UIComponentBase {

    public String getFamily() {
       return "components.jsp.include";
    }

    public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
       try {
          ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
          HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
          HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

          // Create dispatcher for the resource given by the componen's page attribute.
          RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher((String) getAttributes().get("page"));

          // Catch the resource's output.
          CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper(response);
          requestDispatcher.include(request, responseWrapper);

          // Write the output from the resource to the JSF response writer.
          context.getResponseWriter().write(responseWrapper.toString());
       }
       catch (ServletException e) {
          throw new IOException();
       }
    }

}
```

---

Create class `com.example.CharResponseWrapper`

```java
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

   private CharArrayWriter output;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return output.toString();
   }

   public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
      super(response);
      output = new CharArrayWriter();
   }

   public CharArrayWriter getCharWriter() {
      return output;
   }

   @Override
   public PrintWriter getWriter() {
       return new PrintWriter(output);
  }

   @Override
   public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
      return new CharOutputStream(output);
   }

   public InputStream getInputStream() {
      return new ByteArrayInputStream( toString().getBytes() );
   }
}

class CharOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {

   private Writer output;

   public CharOutputStream( Writer writer ) {
      output = writer;
   }

   @Override
   public void write(int b) throws IOException {
      output.write(b);
   }
}
```

---

Add in `faces-config.xml`

```xml
<component>
    <component-type>com.example.component.JSPIncludeComponent</component-type>
    <component-class>com.example.component.JSPIncludeComponent</component-class>
</component>
```

---

Create file `my.taglib.xml` (Facelet taglib) in the WEB-INF folder

```xml
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">

<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://example.com/jsf</namespace> 

    <tag>
      <tag-name>include</tag-name>
      <component>
        <component-type>com.example.component.JSPIncludeComponent</component-type>
      </component>
    </tag>

</facelet-taglib>
```

---

Add to `web.xml` (as explained in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawn.html)

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

This way you can use it as

```xml
<ui:component 
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/jsf"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <my:include page="page.jsp" />
</ui:composition>
```

---

Last but not least, mark his last words

> *I wouldn’t recommend using this as a lasting solution, but it might ease a migration from legacy JSP with smelly scriptlets and all on them to a more sane and modern Facelets application.*

Comment: This approach does not seem to work for me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128023/unable-to-add-jsp-page-to-xhtml-page

Comment: i confirm that this works for xhtml pages too. Are there any downsides to doing something like this? Like some request map variable used by the different FacesContexts that get created...

Comment: @Nerrve: It shares the same HTTP request, so the JSP/Servlet has the chance to access and manipulate all request/session/application attributes which are also in use by JSF. By the way, this is since shortly also available as a reuseable component in OmniFaces (with an improved `HttpServletResponseWrapper` which properly takes character encoding into account). See also https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/components/resourceInclude.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

You can't. JSP and facelets can't be evaluated together - you have only one view handler, and it processes facelets, not JSPs.

`<c:import>` would work if the jsp is accessible via http, and thus its output will be included, not the code.