# <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"> is not working

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have css files under css folder and jsp files under jsp folder and both folders are inside WEB-INF folder. So how can i get the css file inside jsp?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css>
```

I have given path like this.

Comment: Look at console and check if you got 404

Comment: Please give some more info, your directory structure maybe...

Comment: The closing quote is missing for href, can you try after adding that?

Comment: @vivek I assume you meant "closing quote"?

Comment: have to remove everything before css. It should be like href="css/style.css".

Comment: @TiesonT. Yeah, I meant the same. Edited the comment. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i connect my css to my JSP files stored in the WEB-INF folder? Websphere/JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355292/how-can-i-connect-my-css-to-my-jsp-files-stored-in-the-web-inf-folder-websphere)

Answer (score 15):

Try to use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
```

instead of

```
href="../css/style.css
```

Here you are missing right apostrophe. Also check [BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355292/how-can-i-connect-my-css-to-my-jsp-files-stored-in-the-web-inf-folder-websphere) would solve your problem.

### Note:

Also i recommend to you create **resources** folder on the same level as **WEB-INF** then in resources folder create **css** folder and then reference css file as:

```
WEB-INF
resources
  --css
    --styles.css
  --js
    --scripts.js
```

and here how to connect css with page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/styles.css" />
```

I'm using this approach is my web project and everything works correctly.

Comment: Thank you. 
It didn't work for me until I've put this: rel="stylesheet"

Answer (score 4):

The [@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) rule is another way of loading a CSS file:

```
<style>
    @import url('/css/styles.css');
</style>
```

you can import all the styles at the same time using this trick, like:-

```
@import url('/css/header.css') screen;
@import url('/css/content.css') screen;
@import url('/css/sidebar.css') screen;
@import url('/css/print.css') print;
```

Answer (score 1):

Under a previous version of HTML, to reference an external css file in a another folder, the href attribute required the actual file path such as 
    href="./CSS/filename.css"
Using HTML5, I have my css files in a sub-folder and to my amazement, the above approach doesn't work which I could not understand.  I remove the dot at the beginning, that didn't work.  Then I remove the stating slash(/), again it didn't work. It seems HTML5 only requires the actual css file name to work.  So even with the css file in a sub-folder
    href="filename.css" 
works!

Answer (score 0):

In case if the above answers didn't solve your problem.you can access the file by mentioning its full address.It's always better to add the full file path instead of messing around with the Forward slash.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="C:\bacon\WD3.5 Bacon Fansite Start Here\styles.css" >
```

This is the easiest way to access the External File.Just by simply copying the Full address path of the External file into the main File.But make sure that both Files should be in the Same Folder.

Answer (score -4):

```html
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Login Form</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
 </html>
```

Comment: Would be enough this line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">`. And I believe you will accept your own answer later? :)

Comment: got it fixed ? or you just want to add your code you could have edited the question itself.

Comment: @Morpheus hahahaha interesting.