# I can't import a CSS File in a JSP

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, tomcat8

I try to add a CSS file to an JSP which is running on tomcat 8. The CSS just changes the appearance of tables. The CSS file is in the same folder as the JSP. I tried using:

```
<link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but it didn't show any changes. So I tried:

```
<style type="text/css">
<%@ include file="./table.css" %>
</style>
```

But this gives me a weird error, when I try to reach the page in my browser on the first try I get **`404 - Resource not found`** but when I try again it works. What can cause this and is there an easier way to import my CSS file in the JSP? I use a servlet to reach the JSP if that matters.

Edit:// I just checked the WAR File i exported and the WEB-INF Folder only contains my classes the Folders of the HTML and JSP Sites are on the root directory of the WAR file.

Comment: The 404 suggests to me that the path you specify for table.css is not correct.  Check your WAR packaging and deployment.  You should have a WAR file.

Comment: The funny thing with the 2nd try is that the error just appears at the first try to reach the site, when i reload the page the jsp works and even the css shows up.

Comment: Have you tried just using <%@ include file="table.css" %>? Are your JSPs inside WEB-INF directory?

Comment: I used the include statement within the style tag in the page header. My JSPs are in the "WebContent" folder which Eclipse automatically created. the specific JSP i'm talking about is in "WebContent/admin/". The CSS file is in the same dir.

Comment: What is the location of your css file?

Comment: Its in the same directory as the JSP "WebContent/admin"

Comment: Eclipse - two things you don't understand.  I'd recommend learning about how a WAR file is created and check all the things that Eclipse is doing for you behind the scenes.  Remaining ignorant and depending too much on IDEs and wizards to do the right thing is dangerous.

Comment: Did you even look for the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"> is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356695/link-rel-stylesheet-href-css-style-css-is-not-working)

Comment: @duffymo yes i looked for an answer but everthing gives me an 404 or just simply doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't know what to look for.  Find the exploded WAR file that Eclipse created for you and compare it to what you learn when you read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html

Comment: I compared it, in eclipse i had to move the file to the root and it loads without a problem with "<link href="table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put all your .css files in a folder named `/css` right under the root of your WAR.  The path would be `css/table.css`.

Same for JavaScript: create a folder named `/js` right under the root of your WAR. The path to JavaScript is `js/foo.js`

Comment: thx, it helped to solve my problem it's now loading without problems.

Comment: Thx for the oracle link it, so i was thinking in a wrong way with the paths.