# How to include a JSP file in a Facelets file?

Tags: jsp, include, facelets

How can I include a `.jsp` file into a facelet?

Comment: Please don't say "XHTML" when you actually mean "Facelets". While Facelets uses XHTML, XHTML is not per definition Facelets. You'll only get confusing answers. I've edited the title and tags.

Comment: ya.. How to include jsp page in facelet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by default not supported. You need to create a custom component for this. You can find complete examples in [this blog](http://jdevelopment.nl/facelets-legacy-jsp/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106703/how-to-include-a-jsp-page-in-a-facelets-page/6110516#comment14077633_6110516). The [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) component library has a reuseable [`<o:resourceInclude>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude) component for this.

```
<html ... xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
...
<o:resourceInclude path="/foo.jsp" />
```

Comment: thank you so much. I am done with it after 2 days with omnifaces.

Answer (score 0):

The only include mechanisms built into XHTML are [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) and [Xinclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/) (which I suspect has little support among clients).

Generally speaking, if you want to do includes and your platform supports JSP, then you would process the requested page as JSP and use that to perform the include.

Comment: I've never used JSP, but [it doesn't look complicated](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jsp+include).

Comment: To include jsp in jsp use: <%@ include file="lefile" %>